# Dados do banco por dias da semana

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu estava pensando aqui e não consegui compreender o jeito de como isso funcionaria.

Vamos supor que eu tenho 1 banco de dados com 10 post e em uma coluna tivesse "Dia da semana"

```
ID | NOME | DIA DA SEMANA
-------------------------
1  | ALAN | SEGUNDA-FEIRA
2  | ALEX | QUINTA-FEIRA
3  | BIA  | SEGUNDA-FEIRA
4  | CAIO | SEXTA-FEIRA
5  | KAIO | TERÇA-FEIRA
6  | LANA | QUARTA-FEIRA
7  | LUAN | SEGUNDA-FEIRA
8  | EVA  | SÁBADO
9  | ADÃO | DOMINGO
10 | MELO | DOMINGO
```

E quando fosse segunda-feira os meus registro do banco de dados iriam aparecer na minha página inicial, se terça-feira todos com terça iriam aparecer na página inicial e assim sucessivamente.

Alguém poderia me explicar como isso funcionária ?

Comment: Está usando pdo, mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, pegue a data de hoje.
O utilizando o `date()`, ele gera os dias em inglês (Sat, Sun, Mon...), então vou utilizar um array para formtar:

```
<?php
    $data = date('D');   
    $semana = array(
        'Sun' => 'Domingo', 
        'Mon' => 'Segunda-Feira',
        'Tue' => 'Terca-Feira',
        'Wed' => 'Quarta-Feira',
        'Thu' => 'Quinta-Feira',
        'Fri' => 'Sexta-Feira',
        'Sat' => 'Sábado'
    );
$dia_semana = $semana["$data"]; ?>
```

Nota: o `date('D')` gera a data como dia da semana como texto. Se utilizar minúsculo, ele gerará o dia como número.

Agora é simples, basta a SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE DIA_DA_SEMANA = '$dia_semana'";
```

Comment: Vlw man entendi agora vou fazer uns exercícios aqui.

Comment: Bons estudos! :)

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem sua dúvida, seria assim:

```
# Para segunda:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE dia_da_semana = 'SEGUNDA-FEIRA'

# Para terça:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE dia_da_semana = 'SEGUNDA-FEIRA'

# E assim por diante...
```